# Узнать сразу несколько свойств блока

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте,как правильно указать параметр метода css

```
$("#div_1").css(["font-family","text-align"])
$("#div_1").css("font-family","text-align")
$("#div_1").css({"font-family","text-align"})
```

А то эти три варианта не работают.
Спасибо!

Comment: первый вариант должен работать, вы уверены, что правильно обрабатываете результат (возвращается список key=>value)? и какая версия jq, список появился с 1.9

Comment: @kroder,вот https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/7qc9bab9/1/

Comment: ну собсна вопрос в обработке, о чем и была речь, например вот так https://jsfiddle.net/7qc9bab9/2/

Comment: или так https://jsfiddle.net/7qc9bab9/3/

Comment: @kroder,  Большое Спасибо!

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,Большое Спасибо!

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,а не сложно ли Вам еще подсказать,как убрать кавычки и сделать разделитель ;? #div1{font-family:Verdana;text-align:center} Чтобы вот так было

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться кодом @kroder и составить необходимую строку в цикле. Либо можно преобразовать json в моем коде примерно так: https://jsfiddle.net/7qc9bab9/4/

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогли.)